# How to display selected value of dropdown list in table on click of arrow

Tags: html, angularjs

In the code below, it shows the selected value from dropdown list in another panel on click of the arrow and on clicking remove arrow it pushes it back to the same panel. how in the same code instead of pushing data to the panel(selected) can it push data to table inside the panel? With new data added to new row, each time arrow is clicked

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/i18n/angular-locale_da.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="MoveCtrl">

<div class="container">
  <div class="panel-group">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
              <div class="panel-heading">Available</div>
              <div class="panel-body">
                    <select ng-model="availableList" multiple ng-options="x as x.name for x in available" style="width: 800px"></select> 
              </div>
            </div>

    <div ng-init="myVar = 'arrowBack.png'">
        <img ng-src="{{myVar}}" style="height: 100px" value= "add" ng-click="moveItem(availableList[0], available,selected)">


    <div ng-init="myVar = 'arrowForward.png'">
        <img ng-src="{{myVar}}" style="height: 100px" value= "remove" ng-click="moveItem(selectedList[0], selected,available)">
    </div>
</div>

            <div class="panel panel-primary">
              <div class="panel-heading">Selected</div>
              <div class="panel-body">
                <select ng-model="selectedList" multiple ng-options="x as x.name for x in selected" style="width: 800px"> </select> 
              </div>
            </div>

  </div>
</div>

<script>
angular.module('app', []).controller('MoveCtrl', function($scope) {


    $scope.moveItem = function(item, from, to) {

    console.log('Move item   Item: '+item+' From:: '+from+' To:: '+to);

        var idx=from.indexOf(item);
        if (idx != -1) {
            from.splice(idx, 1);
            to.push(item);      
        }
    };

 $scope.selected= [];                                

    $scope.available = [
      {
        id: 1, 
        name: 'bar'
      }, 
      {
        id: 2, 
        name: 'foo'
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'goo'
      }
    ];
  });  
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

It works like http://jsfiddle.net/f1pnw8cq/ .But instead of selected panel i need table there in which data will be pushed from available panel.

Comment: Your question is not clear,can you create a [Minimal,complete,verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You can refer to this http://jsfiddle.net/f1pnw8cq/

Comment: Just replace `ng-option` with `ng-repeat` to draw table

Comment: @yogendarji no it's not working. can you show your approach by editing the code.

Comment: @ASM please check my ans. how to add table in second panel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f1pnw8cq/1/)

You need to replace `select` with `table` in HTML.

```
<table>
   <tr ng-repeat="x in selected">
      <td>{{x.name}}</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

this will add `table` in second panel.

Comment: Thank you. one more question - Is that possible that instead of getting data from panel and setting it on table ,it select data from dropdown list and set on table???   http://jsfiddle.net/rv7c5x8t/

Comment: @ASM You can try something like http://jsfiddle.net/f1pnw8cq/2/ remove `multiple` from `select`.

Comment: @ASM http://jsfiddle.net/8ukbuwby/1/ You need to use `ng-click="moveItem(availableList, available,selected)" `.. see I removed availableList[0] as now model already has selected value